# Is there a way to open the same page of ghost.py in browser?

Tags: python, browser, web-crawler, ghost.py

So I'm opening some page with `ghost.py`

```
ghost.open('http://someUrl.com')
ghost.wait_for_page_loaded()     
ghost.show()
ghost.wait_for_text('some text here')
```

after that user goes to somewhere, so  I don't know the url and don't know the action.is there a way to capture the page with proxy and coockies and url and open the same page in any browser(firefox or chrome or etc..)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess there is not, but I think if you want do something like this could use Selenium, and pass cookies through browsers.